# How to efficiently submit tasks with large arguments in Dask distributed?

Tags: python, dask

I want to submit functions with Dask that have large (gigabyte scale) arguments.  What is the best way to do this?  I want to run this function many times with different (small) parameters.

#### Example (bad)

This uses the concurrent.futures interface.  We could use the dask.delayed interface just as easily.

```
x = np.random.random(size=100000000)  # 800MB array
params = list(range(100))             # 100 small parameters

def f(x, param):
    pass

from dask.distributed import Client
c = Client()

futures = [c.submit(f, x, param) for param in params]
```

But this is slower than I would expect or results in memory errors.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

OK, so what's wrong here is that each task contains the numpy array `x`, which is large.  For each of the 100 tasks that we submit we need to serialize `x`, send it up to the scheduler, send it over to the worker, etc..

Instead, we'll send the array up to the cluster once:

```
[future] = c.scatter([x])
```

Now `future` is a token that points to an array `x` that lives on the cluster.  Now we can submit tasks that refer to this remote future, instead of the numpy array on our local client.

```
# futures = [c.submit(f, x, param) for param in params]  # sends x each time
futures = [c.submit(f, future, param) for param in params]  # refers to remote x already on cluster
```

This is now much faster, and lets Dask control data movement more effectively.

#### Scatter data to all workers

If you expect to need to move the array x to all workers eventually then you may want to broadcast the array to start

```
[future] = c.scatter([x], broadcast=True)
```

#### Use Dask Delayed

Futures work fine with dask.delayed as well.  There is no performance benefit here, but some people prefer this interface:

```
# futures = [c.submit(f, future, param) for param in params]

from dask import delayed
lazy_values = [delayed(f)(future, param) for param in params]
futures = c.compute(lazy_values)
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful! The usage of the future returned by the scatter command (as an argument to a function in your example) is not explained in the documentation.

Comment: within a task (`f` above) is it possible to reference `future` (the broadcasted cluster version of `x`) w/o passing passing it as an arg to `submit`? For example in spark you can broadcast a variable and then just reference it in your tasks using a the global context.