# Scattering data to dask cluster workers: unknown address scheme 'gateway'

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, dask, dask-distributed

I am following the code found on [the accepted answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941528/how-to-efficiently-send-a-large-numpy-array-to-the-cluster-with-dask-array) (the "Chunk then scatter" part) and I get a strange error while trying to scatter a pandas.DataFrame to the workers.

I am working in jupyter notebook if that matters.

I am not sure what this error means, it's quite cryptic, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
from dask_gateway import Gateway
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask

gateway = Gateway()
options = gateway.cluster_options()
cluster = gateway.new_cluster(cluster_options=options)
cluster.scale(10)
client = cluster.get_client()

X_train = ... # build pandas.DataFrame

x = dd.from_pandas(X_train, npartitions=10)
x = x.persist(get=dask.threaded.get)  # chunk locally
futures = client.scatter(dict(x.dask))  # scatter chunks
x.dask = x 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_567/3586545525.py in <module>
      1 x = dd.from_pandas(X_train, npartitions=10)
      2 x = x.persist(get=dask.threaded.get)  # chunk locally
----> 3 futures = client.scatter(dict(x.dask))  # scatter chunks
      4 x.dask = x

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/client.py in scatter(self, data, workers, broadcast, direct, hash, timeout, asynchronous)
   2182         else:
   2183             local_worker = None
-> 2184         return self.sync(
   2185             self._scatter,
   2186             data,

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/client.py in sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    866             return future
    867         else:
--> 868             return sync(
    869                 self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    870             )

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    330     if error[0]:
    331         typ, exc, tb = error[0]
--> 332         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    333     else:
    334         return result[0]

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in f()
    313             if callback_timeout is not None:
    314                 future = asyncio.wait_for(future, callback_timeout)
--> 315             result[0] = yield future
    316         except Exception:
    317             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
    760 
    761                     try:
--> 762                         value = future.result()
    763                     except Exception:
    764                         exc_info = sys.exc_info()

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _scatter(self, data, workers, broadcast, direct, local_worker, timeout, hash)
   2004             isinstance(k, (bytes, str)) for k in data
   2005         ):
-> 2006             d = await self._scatter(keymap(stringify, data), workers, broadcast)
   2007             return {k: d[stringify(k)] for k in data}
   2008 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _scatter(self, data, workers, broadcast, direct, local_worker, timeout, hash)
   2073                 )
   2074             else:
-> 2075                 await self.scheduler.scatter(
   2076                     data=data2,
   2077                     workers=workers,

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/core.py in send_recv_from_rpc(**kwargs)
    893             name, comm.name = comm.name, "ConnectionPool." + key
    894             try:
--> 895                 result = await send_recv(comm=comm, op=key, **kwargs)
    896             finally:
    897                 self.pool.reuse(self.addr, comm)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/core.py in send_recv(comm, reply, serializers, deserializers, **kwargs)
    686         if comm.deserialize:
    687             typ, exc, tb = clean_exception(**response)
--> 688             raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    689         else:
    690             raise Exception(response["exception_text"])

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/core.py in handle_comm()
    528                             result = asyncio.ensure_future(result)
    529                             self._ongoing_coroutines.add(result)
--> 530                             result = await result
    531                     except (CommClosedError, CancelledError):
    532                         if self.status in (Status.running, Status.paused):

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/scheduler.py in scatter()
   5795         assert isinstance(data, dict)
   5796 
-> 5797         keys, who_has, nbytes = await scatter_to_workers(
   5798             nthreads, data, rpc=self.rpc, report=False
   5799         )

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py in scatter_to_workers()
    143     rpcs = {addr: rpc(addr) for addr in d}
    144     try:
--> 145         out = await All(
    146             [
    147                 rpcs[address].update_data(

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in All()
    214     while not tasks.done():
    215         try:
--> 216             result = await tasks.next()
    217         except Exception:
    218 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/core.py in send_recv_from_rpc()
    893             name, comm.name = comm.name, "ConnectionPool." + key
    894             try:
--> 895                 result = await send_recv(comm=comm, op=key, **kwargs)
    896             finally:
    897                 self.pool.reuse(self.addr, comm)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distributed/core.py in send_recv()
    688             raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    689         else:
--> 690             raise Exception(response["exception_text"])
    691     return response
    692 

Exception: ValueError("unknown address scheme 'gateway' (known schemes: ['inproc', 'tcp', 'tls', 'ucx', 'ws', 'wss'])")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd.from_pandas()` does this "partitioning-then-scattering" internally, so you don't have to do it manually anymore. You can directly use the [Dask DataFrame](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html) API on `x`, and the compute should automatically work on your cluster. :)

The [answer you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941528/how-to-efficiently-send-a-large-numpy-array-to-the-cluster-with-dask-array) is from 5 years ago, which is now outdated because Dask has matured a lot since. For instance, `x.dask` now refers to a "high level graph" (recently added feature) instead of a low-level graph. Dask Gateway uses its own URL scheme, and I'm guessing it's not able to interface with this older Dask syntax properly.

Also, note that mixing schedulers (as done in that answer) isn't recommended anymore.

Comment: great! so none of the methods described in that answer is actually needed?

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't *need* them. But, all except the "chunk-then-scatter" approach will still work, and, in fact, the "Don't load data on your client machine" is a good practice in general. :)