# avoid serializing objects in map_blocks calls

Tags: python, dask

I am using Dask with deep learning models and large arrays. In particular, I am trying to get predictions using map_blocks

```
array.map_blocks(model.predict)
```

Since serialization takes time, is there a way to avoid model to be serialized for each call?

Comment: What happens if you scatter the model to the workers beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

At least two broad options:

1. Scatter (as suggested by @Nick Becker in the comments above), rough pseudocode:

```py
fut_model = client.scatter(model)
array.map_blocks(lambda x: fut_model.predict(x))
```

2. Wrap the prediction in a function that will load the required component, here's the pseudocode:

```py
def model_predict(X_chunk):
    model = pickle.load(mypath) # or another loading method
    return model.predict(X_chunk)

array.map_blocks(model_predict)
```

You might also find [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807879/dask-why-is-memory-usage-blowing-up) relevant.